# How do I write data in specific columns in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I've created a list of column labels.

```
columns_labels = ['Phase', 'Nodes', 'Activation Func', 'Batch Size', 'Layers', 'Optimizers', 'Weight Initializers', 'Dropout']

for i in range(1, 101):
    epoch_num = 'E'+str(i)
    columns_labels.append(epoch_num)
```

Now, I have a list of lists that contains data only for 'Nodes', 'Activation Func', 'Batch Size', 'Layers' and epochs 1-100. Looks like this:

```
 [50,  'LeakyReLU',  32,  2,  0.1867888888888889,  0.24796666666666667, 0.26335555555555556, 0.27434444444444445, 0.28184444444444445, 0.29123333333333334, 0.29535555555555554, 0.3013111111111111, 0.3076111111111111, ...........  0.3350444444444444]
```

I need to drop the first 4 values in each list in the  'Nodes', 'Activation Func', 'Batch Size', and 'Layers' columns and the remaining 100 values in the E1-E100 columns that I generated in the for loop above. How would I do that?

NOTE: I'll eventually be appending data to the dataframe that will include  values for 'Optimizers', 'Weight Initializers', 'Dropout'. The values for those columns in the current data does not exist. I'd be fine with them either remaining blank or filled with a predefined value.

Comment: your list is [ [listNode],[listActivation],.....] or [ [first item of Node,first item Activation][second item of Node,....],....[last item of Node,.....] ]?

Comment: Unclear what this has to do with Pandas

Comment: @JoshFriedlander I am writing that data to a Pandas dataframe.

Comment: @Frenchy My apologies but I'm still fairly new to python and such. I'm not sure what you are saying.

Comment: @MixedBeans, how are set your data in list: one list = one category or each list contains an item of each category?

Comment: What I have is a list of lists: `[[50,  'LeakyReLU',  32,  2,  0.1867888888888889,  0.24796666666666667, ....], [50,  'LeakyReLU',  16,  1,  0.1945949785784848,  0.25676848396965847, ....], .....]`. The first 4 values go in columns 2-5 and the remaining values go in columns 9-109.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert each row to a dictionary and use [`df.append()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) to add it to your existing dataframe:

```
selected_columns = ['Nodes', 'Activation Func', 'Batch Size', 'Layers', ...]
rows_to_add = [[50, 'LeakyReLU', 32, 2, ...], [50, 'LeakyReLU', 16, 1, ...], ...]

for row in rows_to_add:
    dictionary = dict(zip(selected_columns, row))
    df = df.append(dictionary, ignore_index=True)
```

You can build `selected_columns` from your `columns_labels`.

Comment: I had considered something like this but really sure how to execute it gracefully. As I mentioned in a comment above I have a list of lists `[[50, 'LeakyReLU', 32, 2, 0.1867888888888889, 0.24796666666666667, ....], [50, 'LeakyReLU', 16, 1, 0.1945949785784848, 0.25676848396965847, ....], .....]`. The first 4 values go in columns 2-5 and the remaining values go in columns 9-109.

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect how you could use it in a loop. Are there more things that are still unclear?

Comment: In the end what I did was write a NA to the fields that didn't have data. It was only a couple of columns so it didn't make the code unwieldy. I'll have to try this at some point and see how it works.